# WorkItemMigration: No images in discussion comments - DevOps2DevOps

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I have done a WorkItemMigration from one DevOps to another DevOps. In my test environment everything worked fine. But in the live system, all the images in the discussion comments are removed. Is there any setting that can cause missing images?

Comment: If I follow the image link I get this error message: 

{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: The user '924c18cd-feab-4e6a-b5d2-840d1ceee5ae\\name.name@company.de' is not authorized to access this resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Which rights am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `PersonalAccessToken` for the source and the target and then set `"tachmentLinks` to  `true`.

This will use the rest API to download the image and ad them as additional attachments on the work item.